# Elasticsearch not analyzed not working in sorting

Tags: php, sorting, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

I have added the mappings for not analyzed option in elasticsearch, it is not working when i sort the results, here is my mapping shows when i use `http://localhost:9200/_river/jdbc/_search`

```
 "mappings": {
    "jdbc": {
        "dynamic_templates": [
            { "notanalyzed": {
                  "match":              "*", 
                  "match_mapping_type": "string",
                  "mapping": {
                      "type":        "string",
                      "index":       "not_analyzed"
                  }
               }
            }
          ]
       }
   }
```

But when i sort the reults it will take the results wrongly like

```
http://localhost:9200/jdbc/_search?pretty=true&sort=field:asc

{ 
    field: "McDermott Will Amery", 
},
sort: [
    "amery"
]
}
```

But i need order the results from A-Z from the starting word in the field

**UPDATE:** River specification in meta

```
http://localhost:9200/_river/jdbc/_meta

{
  "_index": "_river",
  "_type": "jdbc",
  "_id": "_meta",
  "_version": 1,
  "found": true,
  "_source": {
    "type": "jdbc",
    "jdbc": {
      "driver": "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
      "url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname",
      "user": "user",
      "password": "pass",
      "sql": "SQL QUERY",
      "poll": "24h",
      "strategy": "simple",
      "scale": 0,
      "autocommit": true,
      "bulk_size": 5000,
      "max_bulk_requests": 30,
      "bulk_flush_interval": "5s",
      "fetchsize": 100,
      "max_rows": 149669,
      "max_retries": 3,
      "max_retries_wait": "10s",
      "locale": "in",
      "digesting": true
    },
    "mappings": {
      "jdbc": {
        "dynamic_templates": [
          {
            "notanalyzed": {
              "match": "*",
              "match_mapping_type": "string",
              "mapping": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're searching the right index? `_river` is an index for storing river definitions.

Comment: Yes i am using  `http://localhost:9200/_river/jdbc/_meta` to store the index and my query like `{ "type" : "jdbc",  "jdbc" : { ...  },   "mappings": {..} }`

Comment: Ok, but that's only to specify what the JDBC river should be doing, i.e. what data it needs to retrieve from SQL and where it needs to store that data, `_river` is not the index you should be searching. Can you update your question with the river specification you stored in `_meta`?

Comment: I have updated _river specification meta

Comment: Thanks, and last question, what version of the JDBC river and Elasticsearch are you using?

Comment: Elastic version is 1.4.2 and JDBC version is dbc-1.4.0.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your configuration is not correct for what you want to do. Let's start over. First, let's delete your `_river` index and we'll create it from scratch again:

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/_river
```

Now let's create it again but this time by using the [correct configuration](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-jdbc/tree/1.4#parameters-inside-of-the-jdbc-block), i.e.:

1. your mapping needs to be in the `jdbc.type_mapping` field
2. you need to specify a target `index` and `type`where your data is going to be stored

Here is how it would look like

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_river/jdbc/_meta' -d '{
    "type" : "jdbc",
    "jdbc": {
      "driver": "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
      "url": "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname",
      "user": "user",
      "password": "pass",
      "sql": "SQL QUERY",                  <-- add your SQL query
      "poll": "24h",
      "strategy": "simple",
      "scale": 0,
      "autocommit": true,
      "bulk_size": 5000,
      "max_bulk_requests": 30,
      "bulk_flush_interval": "5s",
      "fetchsize": 100,
      "max_rows": 149669,
      "max_retries": 3,
      "max_retries_wait": "10s",
      "locale": "in",
      "digesting": true,
      "index": "your_index",               <-- add this
      "type": "your_type",                 <-- add this
      "type_mapping": {                    <-- add your mapping here
          "your_type": {                   <-- match this with "type" above
            "dynamic_templates": [{
               "notanalyzed": {
                  "match": "*",
                  "match_mapping_type": "string",
                  "mapping": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "index": "not_analyzed"
                  }
               }
            }]
         }
      }
    }
}'
```

Then when your SQL query runs, it will store data inside the `your_index` index and use the `your_type` mapping type.

Finally, you can search your data with the following query:

```
 curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/your_index/your_type/_search?pretty=true&sort=field:asc'
```

**UPDATE**

You may also use the following mapping defining a multi-field. Then you'd be able to sort on the `not_analyzed` field and search on the `analyzed` one:

```
"dynamic_templates": [{
   "multi": {
      "match": "*",
      "match_mapping_type": "string",
      "mapping": {
         "type": "string",
         "fields": {
            "raw": {
               "type": "string",
               "index": "not_analyzed"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}]
```

The query on the field named `field` would then be

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/your_index/your_type/_search?pretty=true&q=field:Luke&sort=field.raw:asc'
```

Comment: I need map some fields only, need to skip other fields in mapping.  so can i use the below attribute `"match": "field, field2, field3",` ?

Comment: What are the exact field names you want to match?

Comment: `pd_fullNameTaxonomy, pd_lawFirmName, jt_tax, et_tax, loc_cityname, location_countryname, location_primary, admitted_date`, I need to sort the results based on the above fields only.

Comment: Are they all `not_analyzed` string fields? `admitted_date` as well?

Comment: I suggest to use [`match_pattern`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html?q=dynamic_templ#match-pattern)  instead of `match`. Try it out and see how it works out given your complete mapping.

Comment: yes above all is `not_analyzed` fields including `admitted_date`.

Comment: So you confirm that `admitted_date` is of type `string` and not `date`?

Comment: there is some issue, when using the not_analyzed option. When we search the field it will return only if the complete string is matched. for ex. I have a word `Luke Ricci`. When i search a word `Luke`. it will return empty. is there any possibility to match the results with both sorting and search?

Comment: Yes, you could have a multi-field. You'd sort against the `not_analyzed` field and search against the analyzed one. I'm updating my answer accordingly.